# Count character 'a' in first n characters of indefinitely repeating string s

Tags: functional-programming, scala, immutability

[Problem statement:](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/repeated-string/problem?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=warmup)

> Lilah has a string, **s**, of lowercase English letters that she
>   repeated infinitely many times. Given an integer, **n**, find and
>   print the number of letter **a**'s in the first **n** letters of
>   Lilah's infinite string.
>
> For example, if the string **s = 'abcac'** and **n = 10**, the
>   substring we consider is **abcacabcac**, the first **10** characters
>   of her infinite string. There are **4** occurrences of **a** in the
>   substring.
>
> **Function Description**
>
> Complete the repeatedString function in the editor below. It should
>   return an integer representing the number of occurrences of **a** in
>   the prefix of length  **n** in the infinitely repeating string.
>
> **repeatedString has the following parameter(s):**
>
> ```
> s: a string to repeat
> n: the number of characters to consider
> ```
>
> **Input Format** The first line contains a single string, **s**.  The second line contains an integer, **n**.
>
> **Output Format**
>
> Print a single integer denoting the number of letter **a**'s in the
>   first  letters of the infinite string created by repeating infinitely
>   many times.
>
> **Sample Input 0**
>
> ```
> aba
> 10
> ```
>
> **Sample Output 0**
>
> ```
> 7
> ```
>
> **Explanation 0**  The first  letters of the infinite string are abaabaabaa. Because there are  a's, we print  on a new line.
>
> **Sample Input 1**
>
> ```
> a
> 1000000000000
> ```
>
> **Sample Output 1**
>
> ```
> 1000000000000
> ```
>
> **Explanation 1**  Because all of the first  letters of the infinite string are a, we print  on a new line.

**My Solution:**

```
def repeatedString(s: String, n: Long): Long = {

  def getCount(str: String): Int = str.groupBy(identity).get('a').map(x => x.length).getOrElse(0)

  val length= s.length
  val duplicate: Long = n / length
  val margin = n % length
  val numberOccurencesInString = getCount(s)
  val countInRepetetiveString = numberOccurencesInString * duplicate

  val numberOfOccurencesInStripedString = getCount(s.take(margin.toInt))

  countInRepetetiveString + numberOfOccurencesInStripedString
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please see [_What to do when someone answers_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). I have rolled back Rev 3 → 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `getCount()` method is a little difficult to read, on one long line like that, and *way* too complicated. `s.count(_ == 'a')` is both concise and efficient.

It's not clear why the number of `s` repetitions possible in `n` is called `duplicate`. It seems an odd choice for that variable name.

Your algorithm is sound, I just find it excessively verbose, especially for a language that prides itself on being both expressive and concise.

```
val sLen = s.length
s.count(_ == 'a') * (n/sLen) + s.take((n%sLen).toInt).count(_ == 'a')
```

Comment: I have considered your suggestions and updated question accordingly. And  thank you for the solution it is expressive(self explanatory).

Answer (score 0):

(Disclamer: It's been quite a while that I used Scala.)

Your code is quite complicated. Scala provides the `LazyList` which allows to virtually repeat the string indefinitely. You then just need to "take" the `n` first characters, filter out the `a`s and count them:

```
def repeatedString(s: String, n: Int) =
   LazyList.continually(s).flatten.take(n).filter(_ == 'a').size
```

(Edit: Changed `n` to an Int. Unfortunately this solution won't work if `n` is a `Long`.)

Comment: [take](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/LazyList.html#take(n:Int):scala.collection.immutable.LazyList[A]) takes Int as parameter. And we are passing Long value for Int. It is giving compiler error. Even if we use n.toInt, there is a possibility of loosing precision. Try Sample Input 1.